# force login page to show first

Tags: php, html

I have my login page working perfectly.

It doesn't use a database of users, It uses predefined username and password within the code. The only thing I'm unable to do is make the login page show first before the index.php. Anyone can type `index.php` and the site opens so it's not using the login page.

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>

<html lang = "en">

<head>
  <title>Alpine VW Extension List</title>
  <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

  <style>
     body {
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #ADABAB;
     }

     .form-signin {
        max-width: 330px;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #017572;
     }

     .form-signin .form-signin-heading,
     .form-signin .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
     }

     .form-signin .checkbox {
        font-weight: normal;
     }

     .form-signin .form-control {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
     }

     .form-signin .form-control:focus {
        z-index: 2;
     }

     .form-signin input[type="email"] {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-color:#017572;
     }

     .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-color:#017572;
     }

     h2{
        text-align: center;
        color: #017572;
     }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>Welcome, Please Login</h2> 
  <div class = "container form-signin">

     <?php
        $msg = '';

        if (isset($_POST["login"]) && !empty($_POST["username"]) 
           && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

           if ($_POST["username"] == "admin" && 
              $_POST["password"] == "admin") {
              $_SESSION["valid"] = true;
              $_SESSION["timeout"] = time();
              $_SESSION["username"] = "admin";

              header("location:index.php");
           }else {
              $msg = 'Wrong username or password';
           }
        }
     ?>
  </div> <!-- /container -->

  <div class = "container">

     <form class = "form-signin" role = "form" 
        action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
        ?>" method = "post">
        <h4 class = "form-signin-heading"><?php echo $msg; ?></h4>
        <input type = "text" class = "form-control" 
           name = "username" placeholder = "username = tutorialspoint" 
           required autofocus></br>
        <input type = "password" class = "form-control"
           name = "password" placeholder = "password = 1234" required>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type = "submit" 
           name = "login">Login</button>
     </form>


  </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check for login in the index page - if they are not logged in redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a session variable something like you have done in the above code is fine.

```
$_SESSION["valid"] = true;
```

Then on your index.php page you need to start the session and check if the valid session variable is set to true and if not redirect back to the login page

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION["valid"] != true){
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

To clear this up from your comment, you simply put this at the top of your index.php file (in PHP tags obviously) and it will check every time your index page is loaded.

Comment: Hello sir @twigg thank you for the response. How would i put this in index.php as im still learning and someone helped me with that part.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!! I have one more question if i could. my page is a contact list. with buttons to Add/Remove contacts. Is there a way I can make it so you have to login first before you can add/remove contacts but you are able to at least see what contacts are already there.